Change variable based on time Batch
I want to change a variable state based on the time of the day.
@echo off
:loop
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
set flag=1

if time is between 0 AND 12 set flag = 0
if time is between 12 AND 24 set flag = 1

for %%x in (51 57 ) do (
    
    if %flag% == 1 (
    Do Stuff
    )

    if %flag% == 0 (
    Do Other Stuff
    )   
)

timeout /t 0

goto loop


if %hour% LSS 12 set flag=0
if %hour% GTR 12 set flag=0

First, you need to get the date, best in a fixed format, independent of locale settings (not like `%date%), then extract the hour and set your flag depending on it. There are several methods, here is one of them:
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('Robocopy.exe \: . /NJH /L^|findstr /b "2"') do if 1%%a lss 112 (set flag=0) else (set flag=1)

this sets flag=0 for time 00:00 to 11:59 and flag=1 for time 12:00 to 23:59.
Note: I added 1 to the hour (so 09 becomes 109), because numbers starting with zero are treated as octal and 08 and 09 are invalid octal numbers, leading to syntax errors).
No second if needed for the afternoon, just a single if - else
